# Hosting MySQL on Heroku

Tags: mysql, spring, heroku

I am building a Spring Boot Web Application using Spring Data JPA to connect to MySQL database. I would like to host this application on Heroku. I went through some of the documentation and it seems like they have more support for Postgres. When Hosting MySQL on Heroku is there any data management interface for this? and is it possible to link a local database interface like workbench on my local machine to point to the mysql database running on Heroku?

Answer (score -1):

[Here](https://elements.heroku.com/search/addons?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=mysql) are the avaiable addons for mysql.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem but easily overcame it with the help of ClearDB add-on in heroku.

Here is a detailed implementation guide. Just follow it according to your requirement. 
https://github.com/yatharthranjan/Spring-Mysql-Test